# Turn off standard notification on experience builder site for partner user

Tags: community, lightning-experience, aura, partner-communities, experience

We have enabled notification in our Experience builder sites. We are creating some custom notifications for partners using customization(flow).

There are 2 types of user a) partner b)customer.

Problem is that whenever a task is being created with **IsReminderSet = true** on a given record for the customer(assigned to),
Standard notifications are also being generated for partner user as they own that record.
In such case, we want to hide the standard notifications for Partners or at least if there is any way to overwrite URL linked with the standard notification.

for e.g
current url '/s/detail/00Txxxxxx' with '/s' using some javascript or by any other means(aura component added on detail page).

Note: We tried writing some JS in head content using window.location.replace but it did not work.
also, we cannot turn off notification as custom notification should be visible